# Ignoring before_validation callback in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a model "declaration" with a `before_validation` callback wich sets the status of new declarations to "open". This works fine, but in my spec I want to quickly test several states. So I create a declaration like this:

```
let!(:declaration) { create(:declaration, status: "approved", user: employee) }
```

Unfortunately, the `before_validation` sets the status to "open" each time.
What is the best way to deal with this in my test?

I could of course do the whole flow so the declaration gets into the correct state (it's a feature spec), but this takes a lot of time because it is slow. The purpose of this part of my test is to check a bunch of different states quickly. Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you even create objects in your specs?

Comment: Hmmm, do you have more info on this? Sounds interesting.

Comment: `build`, `build_stubbed` are generally enough for model specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to modify your before validation.

Sounds like your are actually doing this:

```
self.status = "open"
```

Maybe you should do

```
self.status ||= "open"
```

So, it will set status to open for each new creation, but only when a status is not specify.

Comment: Brilliant! It not only makes my test work, it is a better solution for my application as well as I think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

John, I've used factoryGirl's skip_callback method to skip validations in the past after the build, but just before create. Here's a Stack Overflow that helped me: [Skip callbacks on Factory Girl and Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751175/skip-callbacks-on-factory-girl-and-rspec)