# How to define a skip_callback for :validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a rails model with a

```
validate :existing_invoice, on: :create
```

directive. I would like to skip this callback in rspec. In another question ([Skip callbacks on Factory Girl and Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751175/skip-callbacks-on-factory-girl-and-rspec)), I read to use

```
skip_callback(:validate, :create, :after, :existing_invoice)
```

as solution, but it looks like this doesn't work. (gives an error "undefined local variable or method `after'") How should I implement my skip_callback to do the job?

Comment: See Stackoverflow Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449019/rails-4-skip-callback#answer-19449936

Comment: @Abdul - thanks for "refreshing" this question! I understand they're modifying the callback with an if condition, which however I consider bad practice if you're only doing this because of testing...

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not in favour of modifying callback using condition. Basically I was talking about http://www.allerin.com/blog/save-an-object-skipping-callbacks-in-rails-3-application/