# Rails 4: Skip callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have an auction and a bid object in my application, when someone presses the **BID BUTTON** it then calls the **BID CREATE** controller which created the bid, and then does some other things on the auction object:

BIDS CONTROLLER -> CREATE

```
@auction.endtime += @auction.auctiontimer
@auction.winner = @auction.arewinning 
@auction.save
```

AUCTION MODEL

```
before_update :set_endtime

def set_endtime
   self.endtime=self.starttime+self.auctiontimer
end
```

So the question is: How can C skip the "before callback" only, in this specific @auction.save

Comment: so you don't want to execute the callback if it is a new record? or does it depend on the action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid running ActiveRecord callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632742/how-can-i-avoid-running-activerecord-callbacks)

Comment: @phoet i've tried with that answer but i think doesn't work in rails 4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`skip_callback` is a complicated and not granular option.

I prefer to use an attr_accessor:

```
attr_accessor :skip_my_method, :skip_my_method_2
after_save{ my_method unless skip_my_method }
after_save{ my_method_2 unless skip_my_method_2 }
```

That way you can be declarative when skipping a callback:

```
model.create skip_my_method: true # skips my_method
model.create skip_my_method_2: true # skips my_method_2
```

Comment: I've used this as well. Other methods could run into threading issues.

Comment: considering your approach I have tried slightly different solution which works with `rails 5`.
Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42945367/4675524

Comment: in what way is `skip_callback` not granular?

Answer (score 5):

ActiveSupport::Callbacks::ClassMethods#skip_callback is not threadsafe, it will remove callback-methods for time till it is being executed and hence and another thread at same time cannot get the callback-methods for execution.

Look at the informative post by Allerin - [SAVE AN OBJECT SKIPPING CALLBACKS IN RAILS APPLICATION](http://www.allerin.com/blog/save-an-object-skipping-callbacks-in-rails-3-application/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try skipping callback with skip_callback

[http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods:skip_callback](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods%3askip_callback)

Comment: That's works! Here the useful post about this method: http://manuel.manuelles.nl/blog/2012/01/12/disable-rails-before-slash-after-callback/

Answer (score 2):

You can use update_columns 
See this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks

Is there any specific condition like when you don't have endtime then only you need to set end time if that the you can do

```
def set_endtime 
   if endtime.nil? 
     self.endtime=self.starttime+self.auctiontimer 
   end 
end
```

OR

```
before_update :set_endtime if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.endtime.nil? }
```

Comment: This is a way but skips validations, i want just to skip callbacks :)

Comment: Is there any specific condition like when you don't have endtime then only you need to set end time if that the you can do
def set_endtime
 if endtime.nil?
   self.endtime=self.starttime+self.auctiontimer
 end
end

Comment: Update my answer with example

Comment: This is the correct answer for save/update callbacks!