# Skip callback on create Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, before-filter

I would like to create an Active Record model for Rspec test.

However, this model has callbacks, namely: before_create and after_create method (I think these methods are called callbacks not validation if I am not wrong).

Is there a way to create an object without triggering the callbacks?

Some previous solutions I have tried / does not work for my case:

**Update Method:**

update_column and other update methods will not work because I would like to create an object and I can't use update methods when the object does not exist.

**Factory Girl and After Build:**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :withdrawal_request, class: 'WithdrawalRequest' do
    ...
    after(:build) { WithdrawalRequest.class.skip_callback(:before_create) }
  end
end
```

Failure/Error: after(:build) { WithdrawalRequest.class.skip_callback(:before_create) }

NoMethodError:
undefined method `skip_callback' for Class:Class

[Skip callbacks on Factory Girl and Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751175/skip-callbacks-on-factory-girl-and-rspec)

**Skip Callback**

```
WithdrawalRequest.skip_callback(:before_create)

withdrawal_request = WithdrawalRequest.create(withdrawal_params)

WithdrawalRequest.set_callback(:before_create)
```

Failure/Error: WithdrawalRequest.skip_callback(:before_create)

NoMethodError:undefined method `_before_create_callbacks' for #

[How to save a model without running callbacks in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371734/how-to-save-a-model-without-running-callbacks-in-rails)

I have also tried

```
WithdrawalRequest.skip_callbacks = true
```

Which does not work too.

---------- EDIT -----------

My factory function is edited to:

```
after(:build) { WithdrawalRequest.skip_callback(:create, :before, :before_create) }
```

My before_create function looks like this:

```
class WithdrawalRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_create do
    ...
  end
end
```

---------- EDIT 2 -----------

I changed the before_create to a function so that I can reference it. Is either of these a better practice?

```
class WithdrawalRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :before_create
  ...
  def before_create
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the referenced answer:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :withdrawal_request, class: 'WithdrawalRequest' do
    ...
    after(:build) { WithdrawalRequest.skip_callback(:create, :before, :callback_to_be_skipped) }
   #you were getting the errors here initially because you were calling the method on Class, the superclass of WithdrawalRequest

    #OR
    after(:build) {|withdrawal_request| withdrawal_request.class.skip_callback(:create, :before, :callback_to_be_skipped)}

  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am still having error (it is still doing the callback)
I have edited the question with the before_create do function added. Do you know what could be causing this error? (please look at the edit for more info)

Comment: Can you do this to skip `all` callbacks? For models that has lots of callbacks.