# Factory Girl: want to prevent factory girl callbacks for some traits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have a `FactoryGirl` for a model class. In this model, I defined some traits. In some traits, I don't want FactoryGirl callback calling but I don't know how. For example here is my code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    sequence(:promotion_item_code) { |n| "promotion_item_code#{n}" }

    after :create do |product|
      FactoryGirl.create_list :product_details, 1, :product => product
    end

    trait :special_product do
       # do some thing
       # and don't want to run FactoryGirl callback
    end
end
```

In this code, I don't want `:special_product` trait calls `after :create`. I don't know how to do this.

**@Edit:** the reason I want to this because sometimes I want generate data from parent -> children. But sometimes I want vice versa generate from children to parent. So When I go from children -> parent, callback at parent is called so children is created twice. That is not what I want.

**@Edit 2:** My question is prevent callback from FactoryGirl, not from ActiveRecord model.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip callbacks on Factory Girl and Rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751175/skip-callbacks-on-factory-girl-and-rspec)

Comment: @WesFoster Nope. Please read carefully answer and question first. Your post is about skip ActiveRecord callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes) to achieve that.

Like:

```
factory :product do
  transient do
    create_products true
  end

  sequence(:promotion_item_code) { |n| "promotion_item_code#{n}" }

  after :create do |product, evaluator|
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:product_details, 1, :product => product) if evaluator.create_products
  end

  trait :special_product do
     # do some thing
     # and don't want to run FactoryGirl callback
  end
end
```

But I think that a better way to model this problem is to define a `trait` for the "base case" or to have multiple factories.

Comment: No. The problem still the same because `create_products` always set.

Comment: When you don't want to create the products you should pass the `create_products` in false.

Comment: I'm using association. I don't know the way for passing data. Here is my code:       `association :product, :factory => [:product, :special_product]` thanks

Comment: I think that `association :product,  factory: [:product, :special_product], create_products: false` should work. For more information: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits

Comment: thanks so much. it works :D although I cannot mapping your link (about trait) with your code (use association + trait + custom attributes like transient) :D can you tell me more about this, where can you get this from document. thanks :D

Comment: It isn't the exact same example, but if you search for `association` you should see that it passes attributes to the association like `name: "John Doe"` with the `trait` as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach as described in the Factory Girl docs for a [`has_many` relationship](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations):

```
factory :product_detail do
  product
  #... other product_detail attributes
end

factory :product do
  sequence(:promotion_item_code) { |n| "promotion_item_code#{n}" }

  factory :product_with_details do
    transient do
      details_count 1  # to match your example.
    end

    after(:create) do |product, evaluator|
      create_list(:product_detail, evaluator.details_count, product: product)
    end
  end

  trait :special_product do
    # do some thing
    # and don't want to run FactoryGirl callback
  end
end
```

This allows you to generate data for the parent->children:

```
create(:product_with_details)                   # creates a product with one detail.
create(:product_with_details, details_count: 5) # if you want more than 1 detail.
```

...and for the special product just

```
# does not create any product_details.
create(:product)
create(:product, :special_product)
```

To generate for children->parent

```
create(:product_detail)
```